# Element API CORS issue

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I'm running into this effectively https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI/issues/4 and I'm not quite sure how I'd integrate this change with https://gist.github.com/stevieg83/85dd058dc77a3b46764165975b17bb76 adding it as the first part of my function errors out for me

`syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)`

What's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% untested, but try this:

```
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/jobs.json' => function() {
            HeaderHelper::setHeader([
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://example.com'
            ]);

            return [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => ['section' => 'jobs'],
                'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                    return [
                        'title' => $entry->title,
                        'url' => $entry->url,
                        'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::getUrl("jobs/{$entry->id}.json"),
                    ];
                },
            ];
        },
        'api/jobs/<entryId:\d+>.json' => function($entryId) {
            HeaderHelper::setHeader([
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://example.com'
            ]);

            return [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => ['id' => $entryId],
                'first' => true,
                'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                    return [
                        'title' => $entry->title,
                        'url' => $entry->url,
                        'entryId' => $entry->id,
                        'postDate' => $entry->postDate,
                    ];
                },
            ];
        },
    ]
];
```